# How to put a list of an array into another array with different format

Tags: php, html, arrays

My code is the seguent:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ASUSEMANUELE] => 2
            [BOLLE] => 1
            [BRUNELLA] => 1
            [CHIARA] => 2
            [IMACSONORA] => 2
            [INTERNET] => 1
            [LAB1] => 2
            [LAB2] => 2
            [MARKETING] => 1
            [OFFICE] => 2
            [QUALITA] => 1
            [RAIMONDO] => 2
            [SC] => 2
            [SERVER2K8] => 2
            [SICA] => 1
        )

)
1

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [LEGALE1] => 2
            [LEGALE2] => 1
            [LEGALE3] => 2
        )

)
1
```

And what I would is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ASUSEMANUELE] => 2
            [BOLLE] => 1
            [BRUNELLA] => 1
            [CHIARA] => 2
            [IMACSONORA] => 2
            [INTERNET] => 1
            [LAB1] => 2
            [LAB2] => 2
            [MARKETING] => 1
            [OFFICE] => 2
            [QUALITA] => 1
            [RAIMONDO] => 2
            [SC] => 2
            [SERVER2K8] => 2
            [SICA] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [LEGALE1] => 2
            [LEGALE2] => 1
            [LEGALE3] => 2
        )

)
```

The array is in one php variable (ex. $array), so there are not 2 arrayes separeted... otherwise I would have used the php function array_merge.
How can I do with php? Many thanks

RE-EDIT:
The code I used to generate the array is:

```
$files = glob('logs/*.xml', GLOB_BRACE);
foreach($files as $file) {
    $xmlLog = simplexml_load_file($file);

    foreach($xmlLog->LogsUser->User as $LogsUser): 
        $arr_ks[] = $LogsUser->Name;
        $arr_ch[] = checkLastAccess(date('Y-m-d', rtrim($LogsUser->LastModify)));
    endforeach;

    $c = array(array_combine($arr_ks, $arr_ch));
}
```

LAST EDIT:
XML first array

```
<Logs>
    <LogsUser>
       <UserName>1c:98:ec:0e:9d:98</UserName>
       <User>
          <Name>ASUSEMANUELE</Name>
          <SpaceUsed>143134152</SpaceUsed>
          <Letter>G</Letter>
          <LastAccess>1475596801</LastAccess>
          <LastModify>1475248419</LastModify>
       </User>
       <User>
          <Name>BOLLE</Name>
          <SpaceUsed>857512</SpaceUsed>
          <Letter>M</Letter>
          <LastAccess>1475658001</LastAccess>
          <LastModify>1471844853</LastModify>
       </User>
       <User>
          <Name>BRUNELLA</Name>
          <SpaceUsed>4027220</SpaceUsed>
          <Letter>G</Letter>
          <LastAccess>1475625602</LastAccess>
          <LastModify>1464599323</LastModify>
       </User>
       <User>
          <Name>CHIARA</Name>
          <SpaceUsed>31480800</SpaceUsed>
          <Letter>G</Letter>
          <LastAccess>1475650802</LastAccess>
          <LastModify>1475475835</LastModify>
       </User>
       <User>
          <Name>IMACSONORA</Name>
          <SpaceUsed>29429480</SpaceUsed>
          <Letter>G</Letter>
          <LastAccess>1475665201</LastAccess>
          <LastModify>1475665144</LastModify>
       </User>
       <User>
          <Name>INTERNET</Name>
          <SpaceUsed>40519812</SpaceUsed>
          <Letter>G</Letter>
          <LastAccess>1475661601</LastAccess>
          <LastModify>1473056006</LastModify>
       </User>
       <User>
          <Name>LAB1</Name>
          <SpaceUsed>4180192</SpaceUsed>
          <Letter>G</Letter>
          <LastAccess>1475676002</LastAccess>
          <LastModify>1474982475</LastModify>
       </User>
       ...
   </LogsUser>
   <LogsDisk>
       <Disk>
           <Total>3845561016</Total>
           <Used>1410121024</Used>
           <Status>0</Status>
       </Disk>
   </LogsDisk>
   <LogsVersion>
       <Version>2.0-10</Version>
   </LogsVersion>
</Logs>
```

XML second array

```
<Logs>
    <LogsUser>
        <UserName>1c:98:ec:1e:b0:84</UserName>
        <User>
            <Name>LEGALE1</Name>
            <SpaceUsed>175987628</SpaceUsed>
            <Letter>G</Letter>
            <LastAccess>1475611207</LastAccess>
            <LastModify>1475610761</LastModify>
        </User>
        <User>
            <Name>LEGALE2</Name>
            <SpaceUsed>701804</SpaceUsed>
            <Letter>M</Letter>
            <LastAccess>1475604002</LastAccess>
            <LastModify>1473186312</LastModify>
        </User>
        <User>
            <Name>LEGALE3</Name>
            <SpaceUsed>10949684</SpaceUsed>
            <Letter>G</Letter>
            <LastAccess>1475607602</LastAccess>
            <LastModify>1475606475</LastModify>
        </User>
    </LogsUser>
    <LogsDisk>
        <Disk>
            <Total>1922722952</Total>
            <Used>187851100</Used>
            <Status>0</Status>
        </Disk>
    </LogsDisk>
    <LogsVersion>
        <Version>2.0-10</Version>
    </LogsVersion>
</Logs>
```

Comment: Can you explain more about it being "in one php variable"

Comment: All the block of code in the first window is located in one variable. As you can see from the first block there are two arrays... but I don't think is correct.

Comment: It looks like two variables.  Are you sure you're not printing it in a loop?  Those "1"s also suggest you're doing something like `echo print_r()`

Comment: I recognize there may be a language barrier here, but you need to find a way to better explain what exactly you're trying to do. You have four answers already posted by users who evidently cannot figure out what you want.

Comment: Finally - that last edit helps a lot!

Comment: Sorry... the first block of code is returned from a foreach loop... and this is the reason why I cannot use two variables to define each array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alter your foreach loop -

```
$output = array();
$files = glob('logs/*.xml', GLOB_BRACE);
foreach($files as $file) {
    $xmlLog = simplexml_load_file($file);

    $file_log_user = array();
    foreach($xmlLog->LogsUser->User as $LogsUser){
        $file_log_user[(string) $LogsUser->Name] = checkLastAccess(date('Y-m-d', rtrim($LogsUser->LastModify)));
    }
    $output[] = $file_log_user;
}

print_r($output);
```

It looks like you're actually calling that code twice, hence the two arrays that are being printed.

Comment: Are you getting any errors from the script?  Provided that `$LogsUser->Name` is a string, I see no reason why this wouldn't work.  From the screen shot, it looks like `foreach($xmlLog->LogsUser->User as $LogsUser)` isn't iterating anything

Comment: This is what I obtain if I print the $LogsUser: https://s9.postimg.org/x1zdfa5hb/sdsds.jpg

Comment: Are you printing that from within the inner foreach loop?

Comment: If it's not sensitive, I'd suggest uploading the xml files somewhere - then I can test it myself

Comment: Yes... Now I upload the xml

Comment: Updated - you needed the string cast since it was a simplexmlelement.  You should always develop with your error reporting turned on since it shows up issues right away.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125010/discussion-between-calcinai-and-francesco-esposto).

Answer (score 0):

Most straightforward way is to create a new array and push on what you want -

```
$newArray = [];
array_push($newArray, $firstArray[0], $secondArray[0]);
print_r($newArray);
```

Comment: I only have one variable "$array" that returns the first block of code. So I can't push two arrays in an array.

Comment: In your question you show a dump of 2 arrays. Why do you say you only have one variable called `$array`?

Comment: This is the code used to generate the arrays:
`$xmlLog = simplexml_load_file($file);
           $arr_ks = array();
           $arr_ch = array();
           
           foreach($xmlLog->LogsUser->User as $LogsUser): 
            $arr_ks[] = $LogsUser->Name;
            $arr_ch[] = checkLastAccess(date('Y-m-d', rtrim($LogsUser->LastModify)));
           endforeach;
           $c = array(array_combine($arr_ks, $arr_ch));`

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
foreach($array2 as $val)
{
    $array1[]  = $val;    
}
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/GnZmO)**

Comment: I can't split the arrays. The first block of code is an array defined in a unique variable.

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/sl80Z)

Your case is specific. I would suggest you to create new custom function to do the job and use it appropriately according demand.

```
$newArray = array();
$a = array(array("ASUSEMANUELE" => 2,"BOLLE" => 1,"BRUNELLA" =>"..."));
$b = array(array("LEGALE1" => 2,"LEGALE2" => 1,"LEGALE3" => 2));

function specialArrayMerge($oldArray, $newArray)
{   
    array_push($newArray, array());
    $highestIndex = max(array_keys($newArray));
    foreach ($oldArray as $row)
    {
        foreach ($row as $key => $value)
        {
            $newArray[$highestIndex][$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $newArray;
}

$newArray = specialArrayMerge($a, $newArray);
$newArray = specialArrayMerge($b, $newArray);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($newArray);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: As opposed to something like `var_dump([current($a), current($b)]);`